# No /usr/lib/64 on AIX?

Tags: c, aix

I'm used to compiling 64 bit C application on Solaris, but now when I look at compiling the same application on AIX I'm scratching my head as to where I can find the corresponding location for either:

- `/usr/sfw/lib/64`
- `/usr/lib/64`

So typicalliy my compile (not link) would be something like the following on Solaric SPARC.

```
gcc -m64 -R/usr/lib/64 -Wall -g -c -I./include -fPIC ./test.c -o ./test.o
```

That is for Solaris SPARC 8.

I'm working on AIX 6.1. ...

Any ideas how this works on AIX?

Comment: Does modern AIX have 32-bit libraries at all? What does `file a.out` tell you when `a.out` is the binary for Hello World?

Comment: One more thing, how do I tell is a shared lib on AIX is ELFCLASS64 or not? Meaning if I run the following in /usr/lib: "file libtalloc.so" ---> just returns "libtalloc.so: executable (RISC System/6000) or object module not stripped". What does that really mean with regard to ELFCLASS64 etc? I assume it is 64 bit?

Comment: Hi larsmans, thanks for the comment...the fact that GCC on AIX still has the option for "-maix64" tells me that you can have both 64 bit and 32 bit applications on it. I am just waiting for libgcc to be installed and then I will try the "file a.out"...thnx ;-)

Comment: Hi there, I just ran "file test" (where test is an executable) and it returned "test: 64-bit XCOFF executable or object module not stripped" - which is looking much better now...BUT now can I compile a 64 bit application that uses libraries that just say "libmqm.a: archive (big format)" when using "file" on them?

Comment: @LyntonGrice: did you try just using `gcc -m64` (no extra -R or whatever). The compiler should be able to find the right libs. If not, it will tell you what's missing.

Comment: Hi Mat, I am running AIX 6.1 with GCC 4.2 and if I try the "-m64" option it just gives me the following error: "cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-m64""....so that is why I am using the "-maix64". I can try just leave out the -R option, in fact I just tried and "-R" does not seem to be recognized on AIX...that could be a good thing...will check it out

Comment: AIX is a strange and unique environment. Where did you get your GCC for it?

Answer (score 1):

Do:

ar -X 32_64 /lib/libc.a

and notice the output verses without the -X 32_64.  Each library has both 32 bit and 64 bit objects in them.  The tools assume you want 32 bit objects but you can change that default either by an environment variable or command line options.